# SQL Update table based on another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables
T1 (month+year is unique)

```
 month  year    amount 
  10      2015     5000  
  11      2015     4000
```

T2

```
  month   year     amount 
  10      2015      100
  10      2015      200
  10      2015      200
  11      2015      200
```

I want to update the amount field of T1 as follows
T1.amount = T1.amount - (sum of amount in T2 for matching month,year)

So after update T1 shall look like this

```
  month    year   amount
     10       2015    4500 
     11       2015    3800
```

I am not expert at SQL, kindly suggest SQL to achieve the above, thanks !

Comment: Guys, these solutions worked on SQL when i tried in online test tools but both of the below solutions do not work on android sqlite , it gives syntax error at "AS" and "INNER" keywords, pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` to a derived table containing the sum per month/year of `Table2`:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 AS T1
JOIN ( SELECT month, year, SUM(amount)  AS amount
       FROM TABLE2 
       GROUP BY month, year) AS T2
  ON T1.month = T2.month AND T1.year = T2.year
SET T1.amount =   T1.amount - T2.amount;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aee23/1)

**Edit:**

In sqlite you have to use a correlated subquery to do the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET amount =  amount - (SELECT SUM(amount)  
                        FROM TABLE2 
                        WHERE TABLE1.month = TABLE2.month AND 
                        TABLE1.year = TABLE2.year);
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/52ac9/1)

Comment: Giorgos, solution worked on SQL when i tried in online test tools but this  do not work on android sqlite , it gives syntax error at "AS" keyword, pls help

Comment: @user3796596 You have tagged the question with mysql. sqlite probably has a slightly different update syntax.

Comment: @user3796596 Please check the edit I made. It should work in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE T1 
INNER JOIN 
(    
  SELECT 
    `month`,
    `year`,
     SUM(amount) totalAmount
  FROM T2
  GROUP BY `month`,`year`  ) t
ON t.`month` = T1.`month` AND t.`year` = T1.`year`
SET T1.amount = T1.amount - t.totalAmount;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e037f/1/0)

**Explanation:**

The inner query will sum up the amount for each (month,year) pair.

Inner Query:

```
SELECT 
`month`,
`year`,
SUM(amount) totalAmount
FROM T2
GROUP BY `month`,`year`
```

For your sample data it returns result like below:

I named it `t` table

```
month   year totalAmount

10      2015       500

11      2015       200
```

Now if you join this `t` table with your T1 table ON `month` and `year`

that means rows from two tables will be joined only if `T1.month equals t.month` `and T1.year equals t.year` **AND** only then you will update the corresponding amount of T1 table's row like below:

`T1.amount = T1.amount - t.totalAmount`

So after this update your `T1 table` should look like below:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM T1
```

Result:

```
month     year    amount

10        2015     4500

11        2015     3800
```

**Edit:** 
You tagged the question `MySQL` while you are expecting query to work in SqlLite. 
SQLlite [doesn't support JOIN in Update statements](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Sqllite query:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.amount = T1.amount - (
    SELECT
        SUM(T2.amount)
    FROM
        T2
    WHERE
        T1.`month` = T2.`month`
    AND T1.`year` = T2.`year`
);
```

Comment: Please let me know if I've been able to make you understand this. @user3796596

Comment: Subrata, solution worked on SQL when i tried in online test tools but this  do not work on android sqlite , it gives syntax error at "JOIN" keyword, pls help

Comment: Please check the sql lite update query in `Edit` seciton. @user3796596